# How do I exclude a specific record in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, operators, record

I want to exclude a record in my table but it is not working logically. Here is my `Weapons` table:

```
Name / DPS / Style

Noxious Bow / 1000 / Range
Chaotic Staff / 800 / Magic
Armadyl Crossbow / 750 / Range
Saradomin Godsword / 600 / Melee
Dragon Longsword / 600 / Magic
Dragon Longsword / 550 / Melee
Elder Shortbow / 500 / Range
```

What I'm trying to do is exclude the record `Dragon Longsword` which has a `Style` of `Melee`.

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM Weapons
Where Name!='Dragon Longsword' AND Style!='Melee';
```

What is happening is that it is not displaying any record that contains `Dragon Longsword` or `Melee`. I want it to not display only the following record:

```
Dragon Longsword / 550 / Melee
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Logically, what you want is:

```
not (name == 'Dragon Longsword' and Style == 'Melee')
```

Applying simple boolean logic ([De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), thank you @Rocket), this can be translated into:

```
name != 'Dragon Longsword' or Style != 'Melee'
```

So the correct query would need an `OR`, not an `AND`, as unintuitive as it may seem:

```
SELECT *
FROM Weapons
Where Name!='Dragon Longsword' OR Style!='Melee';
```

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: Thanks for providing the real name.  Never knew what it was called :)

Comment: I just happened to remember that from my early CS classes :-)

Comment: P.S. It may be more verbose, but `Where NOT (Name='Dragon Longsword' AND Style='Melee')` is actually valid SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Weapons 
Where Name!='Dragon Longsword' OR Style!='Melee'
```